# docker-compose is not starting cli throws eror : not foundrypoints.sh: ./.env: line 2:

Tags: linux, docker, sbt-docker-compose

I have an amazee.io setup done and the containers were building fine but now I see a strange error while doing cli of the container up the container doesn't starts and exits by itself and throws the error as below -
: not foundrypoints.sh: ./.env: line 2:

This is quite strange as build was successful and every file permissions looks good.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

Change Line separator from CRLF to LF in your entrypoint file. You may find the switcher at the bottom-right of the intellij or vscode ide.